# commandButton to commandLink in a login form

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml, j-security-check

This is my xhtml login page ...

```
<div id="externalborderReg">
    <p:spacer height="70px" />
    <div id="loginForm" >
       <h:form id="login" onsubmit="document.getElementById('login').action='j_security_check';" prependId="false">
          <h:panelGrid columns="2">
             <p:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Email:" />
             <p:inputText id="j_username" name="j_username" placeholder="Email" required="true"/>
             <p:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password:" />
             <p:password id="j_password" name="j_password" placeholder="Password"  required="true" />
          </h:panelGrid>
          <p:spacer height="40px"/>
          <div id="loginButton">
             <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Login" ajax="false" />
          </div>
       </h:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i want to make the p:commandButton a h:commandLink but if i try change it the login button/link stops working ... how can i cahnge it???

Please help me ...

Comment: I've never seen this `onsubmit` usage, where did you get that from?

Comment: That's the code which works, what have you tried indeed? What do you mean by *stops working*? Any errors at javascript console?

Comment: i've found the onsubmit usage on the primefaces showcases site, it works fine ...                                                            stops working in thesense that the login button stops working indeed on click nothing where submitted and the page does not change ... and noone cna log on